# Are there different clients for Quorum compared to Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, quorum, clients

Is it correct to say the following?

Ethereum clients run Ethereum nodes. Geth and Parity are examples of Ethereum clients.

Quorum clients run Quorum nodes.  Is there an equivalent to Geth and Parity for Quorum or can they also be used to run Quorum nodes?

Thanks
Madeline

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is a single client for quorum based on geth. There are plans from EEA to release another one once the spec is locked down (which I think it is). Quorum consists of at least 2 pieces of software tho: client + privacy providing enclave. Originally, Quorum team released only Constellation, but theres been work done to create another one called Crux.

Answer (score 0):

The official Quorum is written in go and is based on Geth source code with a lot of modifications to include private transactions and iBFT among other features. I didn't hear about other clients availables for Quorum for the moment.